# Running python script on parrotOS

Tags: python-3.7

quiero ejecutar un script en python pero tengo un problema a la hora de ejecutar me indica que hay un error en el codigo y no puedo ejecutar he intentado varias formas pero veo que no puedo avanzar [image: Ejecución del script en python]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y no seria mas facil poner en la pregunta el codigo, asi podemos corregir el problema??? si te dice que hay un error, te puedo asegurar que hay un error...

Comment: Un `print` sin paréntesis está indicando que ese código está hecho para **python 2.x**, posiblemente python 2.7. Al parecer estás tratando de ejecutarlo con Python 3.x, y por eso salta el error.

Comment: Que solución debo optar para opder corregir este error?

Comment: Si no querés optar por un downgrade, podés editar tu código para adaptarlo a python 3 (en el caso del print, solo tenés que rodear lo que viene después de print con parentesis). Si es mucho código, busca la librería py2to3, que está diseñada para pasar python 2 a 3. Viene con python, pero esta "en desuso" (la piensan eliminar).